# GLUT on VS 2019

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to use opengl on visual studio 2019
But whenever I want to compile my project I get error saying glut.h is not defined

What I tried:
Copy on glut32.dll
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gl”
and
copy glut32.lib
on “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64”

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define GAP 10
int main_w, w1, w2, w3, w4;
void
display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glFlush();
}
void vis(int visState)
{
  printf("VIS: win=%d, v=%d\n", glutGetWindow(), visState);
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
  int width = 50;
  int height = 50;
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
  if (w > 50) {
    width = (w - 3 * GAP) / 2;
  } else {
    width = 10;
  }
  if (h > 50) {
    height = (h - 3 * GAP) / 2;
  } else {
    height = 10;
  }
  glutSetWindow(w1);
  glutPositionWindow(GAP, GAP);
  glutReshapeWindow(width, height);
  glutSetWindow(w2);
  glutPositionWindow(GAP + width + GAP, GAP);
  glutReshapeWindow(width, height);
  glutSetWindow(w3);
  glutPositionWindow(GAP, GAP + height + GAP);
  glutReshapeWindow(width, height);
  glutSetWindow(w4);
  glutPositionWindow(GAP + width + GAP, GAP + height + GAP);
  glutReshapeWindow(width, height);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(210, 210);
  main_w = glutCreateWindow("4 subwindows");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutVisibilityFunc(vis);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  w1 = glutCreateSubWindow(main_w, 10, 10, 90, 90);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutVisibilityFunc(vis);
  glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  w2 = glutCreateSubWindow(main_w, 110, 10, 90, 90);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutVisibilityFunc(vis);
  glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  w3 = glutCreateSubWindow(main_w, 10, 110, 90, 90);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutVisibilityFunc(vis);
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  w4 = glutCreateSubWindow(main_w, 110, 110, 90, 90);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutVisibilityFunc(vis);
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;             /* ANSI C requires main to return int. */
}
```

E1696   cannot open source file "GL/glut.h"

What I have to do to fix the issue?
PS: I know I can Cmake the source and include them on my project but don't want to fix it only for one project I want to make my visual stdio working with Open GL because I have many other opengl projects

Comment: I’ll bet that’s not exactly what the error says. Please [edit] your question to include your code and the exact error message.

Comment: ***What I tried: Copy on glut32.dll “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gl” and copy glut32.lib on “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64”*** You should never put files in these locations. Also neither of these files will fix a missing header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glut.h isn't part of OpenGL itself. It's part of a separate library named GLUT. Unfortunately, GLUT is known to be somewhat on the buggy side, and hasn't been updated since 1998, so the bugs will probably never get fixed.

If you're just interested in building and running this code, it'll probably work well enough though.

[Glut Downloads](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php)

There are also a couple of projects you might consider as alternatives/replacements:

1. [FreeGlut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)
2. [OpenGlut](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/)

I'd guess either of these will probably have enough compatibility to compile and test the code you're looking at, but I haven't tested it, so that's difficult to say for sure.

My own advice would be that about as soon as you're done looking at the existing code, you move away from Glut and use something else. There are lots of alternatives out there that make a lot of things much easier than Glut even attempts.